# Is there a way to permanently allow apache to upload files to wordpress installations?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, wordpress

I have a development server with several instances of wordpress installed, and am adding instances constantly.  I have an issue where the server uploads files as the apache user & group, but the `wp-content/uploads` folder (as well as all of the other wordpress files) belong to ftpuser / psacln.  I can `chmod` the folder to give apache the proper permissions, but this is frustrating to do for every installation. Is there some way I can change the user/group permissions so that this no longer happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the apache user to the psacln group and make the folder writable for the group.